# how to fix environment error in open-ai gym?

Tags: python, openai-gym

code:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/danie/Downloads/Programming/Python/Programming/Pycharm/app.py", line 40, in 
gym.make("Breakout-v0")
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 156, in make
return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 101, in make
env = spec.make(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 72, in make
cls = load(self.entry_point)
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 17, in load
mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib_init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 967, in find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 677, in load_unlocked
File "", line 728, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\atari_init.py", line 1, in 
from gym.envs.atari.atari_env import AtariEnv
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\atari\atari_env.py", line 9, in 
import atari_py
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\atari_py_init.py", line 1, in 
from .ale_python_interface import *
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\atari_py\ale_python_interface.py", line 18, in 
'ale_interface/build/ale_c.dll'))
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes_init.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
return self.dlltype(name)
File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes_init.py", line 356, in init
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get around this problem with help from the following website: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-openai-gym-in-a-windows-environment-338969e24d30.

There were basically 3 things I had to do: 1) install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools, 2) install this specific verion of Atari https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py.git, 3) Install Xming. Good luck to all Windows users :) This took me around 3 days to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to make it work with python 3.8 and 3.9 on Windows 10. Installing Python 3.7 and using it as the Python Interpreter on PyCharm resolved the issue. I have searched for the missing file while having 3.8 + version of Python and it did not exist at all. Atari-py is supported only for Python 3.7 (https://github.com/openai/atari-py) so having a higher version of that would not work. It is a bad idea to download files from unlicensed places so I advise you to install the supported version of Python (3.5, 3.6, and 3.7). Even though gym can work on 3.9 the atari version will not.  I did not need anything else installed (although I may have Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools, but I deff did not need Xming), just import gym 0.18.0, pyglet 1.5.0, atari -py 0.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. If you trace the exception trace you see that a shared object loading function is called in ctypes' init.py file aliased as dlopen. On Windows, this correponds to WINAPI's LoadLibrary method. **LoadLibrary** is trying to load ale_c.dll. ALE is 'arcade learning environment'.

Search your computer for `ale_c.dll` or `libale_c.dll`

If you have `ale_c.dll` (most likely you are on Windows), refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475912/11666391) to see how DLL's loaded with ctypes are basically LoadLibrary calls as I mentioned. It mentions all the stuff about DLL loading order etc. but, if you need a quick way around this, copy your dll under system32 folder.

Comment: Hi Sıddık Açıl. Thank you for responding to me :) I found the file: 'ale_c.dll'. Sadly I wasn't able to find the file: 'libale_c.dll'. I hope that doesn't make too much change. What should I do next?

Comment: ok, I'm currently in my System32 folder, what '.dll' file is it?

Comment: Copy ale_c.dll to that folder.

Comment: Ok, I've done that so what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Run your program again.

Comment: Well, add more details to the question then. So other people may help, too. What version of windows are you using and what are your steps to install openai-gym?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and if I want to install gym I will just type: 'pip install gym' in command prompt. I'm using gym version: 0.13.0.

Comment: I deleted gym and reinstalled it on my Windows laptop. Your code ran flawlessly. But my ale_c.dll was in `ale_interface/ale_c.dll`, not in `ale_interface/build/ale_c.dll` . Go to your `ale_interface` folder`. Create a folder called `build` if it does not exists. Place ale_c.dll under this folder. You are good to go.

Comment: It's already in `ale_interface/build/ale_c.dll` I tried to delete the build folder because I got the same error and instead placed the `ale_c.dll` in the `ale_interface` folder by itself. I also got an error.

Comment: After you place the dll under ale_interface, you got the same error?

Comment: Yes, the absolutely same

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516002/python-reading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-126) answer. You have the dll everything seems fine but it is not loading. There seems to be a dependency missing in your computer which ale_c.dll uses.

Comment: Download depends.exe and run it. Then, open ale_c.dll through this program. It will show you what is missing. You most probably do not have MSVCP140D.dll or VCRUNTIME140D.dll.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. It's nice that you're helping me. Thanks again :)

Comment: where can I download depends.exe?

Comment: Google "dependency walker".

Comment: My computer is saying: "The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program"

Comment: Open depends.exe then select file and click open. Then choose ale_c.dll from file browse dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Atari-Pacman. It is resolved by downloading atari_py-1.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 which is for 64-bit Python 3.7, and installing it by using pip.

Comment: just with 'pip install atari_py-1.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64'?